# What are the green columns/lines mean in Activity Monitor - Energy - Battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery, activity-monitor

What do these green columns in activity monitor - energy - battery mean? I've included a screen shot of activity monitor - energy if that helps.

[image: activitymonitor]

Answer (score 2):

Since your battery level was rising throughout that period, the green columns would indicate that your laptop was charging/plugged in.

Comment: Green = power cord plugged in (charging or fully charged)