# Why does the Activity Monitor Battery graph and Battery system preference show different charging history?

Tags: macos, battery, charging, activity-monitor

In [What are the green columns/lines mean in Activity Monitor - Energy - Battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/280694), the answer tells that green shading in the Activity Monitor battery graph indicates charging time.

However, the Battery system preference shows a different charging pattern, which is a more accurate representation.

The Activity Monitor graph wouldn't make sense since the charge level is not increasing in the green shaded area. Is this a bug or does the green shading mean something else?

Screenshots below, taken within the same minute:

[image: activity monitor]
[image: battery settings]

System information:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- macOS Big Sur (11.6)

Comment: The activity monitor readout is older and less accurate. It is filling in blanks with (incorrect) information.

Comment: @Ezekiel that would make sense, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Not that I know of - this is just based on experience